# How to use subfunctions to get image. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this problem: I am trying to take an image from url and then show it in my tkinter 'app'. As you can see there is 2 solutions in my head, but only one of them is working (Solution 1). So my wonder here is how can I get the solution 2 work, so that python wouldn't erase my img before it's been added to the panel? I know that after run, functions erases all variables and objects that are not called globally, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

As you can see, I am kinda starter creating apps and asking help in forums, so all tips and tricks are welcome and thank you beforehand!

(One questions about the code I put above: Should I be more specific on my code, like explain more what every piece of code is doing etc?)

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import requests
from io import BytesIO
```

#### SOLUTION 1

```
root = tk.Tk()
img_url = "https://www.countryflags.io/be/flat/64.png"
response = requests.get(img_url)
img_data = response.content
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)))
panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.mainloop()
```

#### SOLUTION 2

```
def image():
   img_url = "https://www.countryflags.io/be/flat/64.png"
   response = requests.get(img_url)
   img_data = response.content
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)))

   panel['image'] = img

root = tk.Tk()
panel = tk.Label(root)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
image()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I did not keep reference to the 'img', so it got erased by python default carbage collector. That's how python works, so just add reference like (panel.image = img), and it should work!

```
def image():
   img_url = "https://www.countryflags.io/be/flat/64.png"
   response = requests.get(img_url)
   img_data = response.content
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)))
   panel.image = img # <-- This needs to be as a reference to the img!
   panel['image'] = img

root = tk.Tk()
panel = tk.Label(root)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
image()
root.mainloop()
```